# codeigniter and piwik with benedmunds authentication

Tags: php, codeigniter, matomo

I have a codeigniter application built using benedmunds authentication model. I'm currently setting up piwik however I was hoping to create a link in the admin panel which opens up piwik.

I'm not worried about piwik getting login details from codeigniter db. I'm also happy to add identical users into piwik, however when a user logs into codeigniter, it needs to automatically be logged into piwik. I don't want a user to have to login twice.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the PiWik source and see how it authenticates.  Most likely you can then just replicate the logic to create the needed session data.

That can then be put into an Ion Auth hook to be called after a successful login.